# Circular Dependency in Backbone / RequireJS Nested List

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, circular-dependency

I'm setting up a nested categories structure in Backbone with RequireJS.

In this structure, a categories collection contains category models, and a single category model can contain a categories collection.

Unfortunately this seems to cause the dreaded circular dependencies problem in RequireJS.  I have read the docs on RequireJS (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) however I am finding the explanation with 'a' and 'b' confusing.

Here is my code, which is causing the problem:

```
define([

    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "collections/categories"

    ], function( $, _, Backbone, CategoriesCollection ) {

    var Category = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            title: "Untitled"
        },

        parse: function(data) {
            this.children = new CategoriesCollection( data.children, {parse: true} );
            return _.omit( data, "children" );
        }

    });

    return Category;

});
```

...

```
define([

    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "models/category"

    ], function( $, _, Backbone, CategoryModel ) {

    var Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: CategoryModel
    });

    return Categories;

});
```

I am wondering if anyone who has experienced this before can help steer me in the right direction.

Thanks (in advance) for your help,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to use `require` the collection again when you need it in the model, as the Collection passing initially can be undefined:

```
define([

    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "collections/categories"

    ], function( $, _, Backbone, CategoriesCollection ) {

    var Category = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            title: "Untitled"
        },

        parse: function(data) { 
            if(!CategoriesCollection){
              CategoriesCollection = require("collections/categories");
            }

            this.children = new CategoriesCollection( data.children, {parse: true} );
            return _.omit( data, "children" );
        }

    });

    return Category;

});
```

In the example they import also `require` but it should also work without the import.

Comment: Man - I've been trying to figure out a circ dependency problem in one of my projects and this really helped me out - thanks bunches.

Comment: This might cause problems since loading of the collection the second time might be async?

Answer (score 0):

For this you should consider to use a plugin like [Backbone Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational).

Comment: Thanks, I did look at Backbone Relational.  I have a feeling that for a simple nested list, which is all I need, it is a bit overkill.