# Backbone and RequireJS: Nested collections/models

Tags: recursion, backbone.js, requirejs

I want to use a recursive Model/Collection structure to model a tree. I am struggling to get the circular reference to work with RequireJS. I use the CommonJs syntax rather than AMD. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "Models/TestModel" has not been loaded yet for context: _
```

TestModel

```
define(function (require) {
    var

    // Dependencies.
    Backbone = require('backbone'),
    TestCollection = require('Collections/TestCollection'),

    TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function (model) {
            this.Children = new TestCollection(model.Children);
        }
    });

    return TestModel;
});
```

TestCollection

```
define(function (require) {

    var Backbone = require('backbone'),
        TestModel = require('Models/TestModel'),

        TestCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: TestModel
        });

    return TestCollection;
});
```

Is this possible with Backbone and RequireJS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular Dependency in Backbone / RequireJS Nested List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324535/circular-dependency-in-backbone-requirejs-nested-list)

Comment: I've tried that - it doesn't work. I'm using CommonJs syntax rather than AMD so there is that difference too.

Comment: You did not read the Q&A there carefully. It pays to read everything. The question mentions [this part of the RequrieJS documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular).If you read it, you'll see examples of circular dependencies that use the CommonJS idiom. Once you understand the principles, then which idiom you use does not matter.

Comment: But the answer given doesn't mention the CommonJs idiom does it?